# facebook sharer with custom params not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a rails 3 application which use facebook sharer with custom params. The facebook sharer works fine except for the picture parameter ! Sometimes it works... and sometimes not !

Can someone tell me why this code display the image :

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&amp;p[title]=Title here&amp;p[url]=http://example.com&amp;p[images][0]=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Kaasmarkt2_close.jpg&amp;p[summary]=I love cheese" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

But not this code :

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&amp;p[title]=Title here&amp;p[url]=http://example.com&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.sharewizz.com/assets/Just_wizz_it.png&amp;p[summary]=I love cheese" target="_blank">Test2</a>
```

Comment: The second image is too small - minimum size is 200px in both directions.

Comment: Thanks, but, how did you know that ?

Comment: It's just to put your image at least 200px in both direction and use the og tags, no ? Have you tried? @JérémyPouyet

Comment: To test, you can use this link as a debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1):

As of mar/feb 2014 update, the sharer no longer accepts custom params. See [response from Facebook engineer](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/357750474364812/?comment_id=308955395926697).

They now recommend using the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) method of sharing.

Answer (score 0):

See Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/

sharer.php only takes the URL as parameter and parses the Open Graph Tags directly from that URL.

Open Graph Tags: http://ogp.me/

About image sizes for OG Tags: http://blog.gocarrot.com/blog/2013/09/16/upcoming-newsfeed-changes/

Comment: No, you can share custom links by passing params to sharer.php. See that : http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-facebook-share-button-for-your-iframe-tab/

Comment: maybe you can, but you shouldn´t ;)

Comment: Why ? And if it's not a good solution, how could I get multiple facebook share on a same page ?

Comment: because only the url parameter is in the facebook docs, and it´s easier for a whole website to just add the open graph tags directly on the page and use sharer.php only by adding the url.

Comment: multiple shares i would do with FB.ui (JavaScript SDK), but normally you don´t need multiple shares. every share should be one specific url. multiple shares are usually only used on those spam pages where you can share a small spam text :)